# Mediation analysis - Covariates

Tags: mediation, predictor

I am doing a parallel mediation analysis using PROCESS, model 4. 
If I understood correctly, when doing mediation analysis for model with multiple IV, all IV, apart from the one that is placed as predictor should be treated as covariates? 
However, what I am interested in, is there any reason why we should not include some of  IV as covariates? For example, if my regression analysis showed that some IV are not significant predictors of DV, could it be a reason not to include them as covariates?

Comment: Some IVs may be a not significant predictor in simple regressions but being so after controlling for other IVs. Moreover, it may happen sometimes to not have a significant global effect, but to find a significant indirect effect anyway: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6019768/ . Thus, I wouldn't exclude any IV based on considerations on statistical significance. In general, in any regression model, variables that are not statistically significant can be included to guarantee the interpretation of the effect of other variables as being conditional on them.